# Docker container log: "No log line matching the '' filter"

Tags: docker, logging

I am building an application which will run with docker. So far it is running fine. However I'm trying to add another service now. I try to create a basic container first with a Dockerfile. I can build and up everything without errors. The newly container stops woorking immediatly. Looking the log section (in the portainer) i can read "No log line matching the ' ' filter.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04


RUN apt-get update
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems like you're missing most of the Dockerfile; what code actually produces that error message?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  (What source code are you `COPY`ing into the container?  What is the main container `CMD`?  How are you starting the container?)